# SAPUI5 make browser remember login / password

Tags: authentication, sapui5

I am developing a SAPUI5 Application.

The pages asks for username and passwort (HANA DB User credentials)

The .xsaccess file looks like this:

```
{ 
   "exposed" : true, 
   "authentication" : { "method" : "Form"},
   "prevent_xsrf" : true
}
```

**How can I make the Browser remember the passwort?**
Or even better "keep logged in"

The main problem is that the login times out after a while - which is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with SAPUI5 as the login occurs before the framework is loaded.

You can however set the session timeout of your XS-Engine to a higher value. To do that go to `Configuration` > `xsengine.ini` > `httpserver` and set the `sessiontimeout` parameter to a larger value (the unit is seconds).

Comment: Thx - This is helpful.